# Block access to login from non-browser clients

Tags: javascript, forms, security, authentication

I have read a lot on the subject and know that it's almost impossible to tell if your form is being submitted by an unauthorized client or browser, and it seems Captcha is loosing it's effectiveness these days since it can be easily read with some machine learning and OCR methods.

One way it seems to help in this case is to make the login or form submit complicated using JavaScript but I'm sure it can be simulated somehow with a robot that loads a Webkit or something.

Here when I'm talking about robot I'm talking about a phishing app that users falsely believe is legit and provide their username and password to login and the app uses our web form to login the user.

I'm tasked with blocking it's access but all I can think of is to identify the IP address and block that on our firewall since any other way can't work.
I was just wondering what are some big companies like Google and Microsoft and Facebook doing to secure unauthorized access to their login forms, since I'm sure they have a solution for that, or are they the potential victim too?

I appreciate any insight on this topic.